# Which package provides virt-install CLI tool in Yocto?

Tags: virtual-machine, yocto, kvm, libvirt, virsh

Does anyone know which package provides virt-install CLI tool in Yocto or how to use virt-install tool in yocto environment?
I have added below packages in my bb file but I don't see virt-install tool getting built

```
packagegroup-core-boot \
qemu \
libvirt \
libvirt-libvirtd \
libvirt-virsh \
libvirt-python \
kernel-module-kvm \
kernel-module-kvm-intel \
kernel-module-kvm-amd \
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure about Yocto, but I think `virt-manager` usually provides `virt-install`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).